# Add custom object powershell

Tags: powershell

The script works with no issue but instead of out put i want to use custom object

```
####################
# Get AD Site List # 
####################
Write-Verbose “Get AD Site List `r”
[array] $ADSites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites 
$ADSitesCount = $ADSites.Count
Write-Output “There are $ADSitesCount AD Sites `r”

ForEach ($Site in $ADSites)
    {  ## OPEN ForEach Site in ADSites
        $SiteName = $Site.Name
        $SiteSubnets = $Site.Subnets


        Write-Output “Site Name: $SiteName `r”
        Write-Output “Site Servers: $SiteServers `r”
        Write-Output ” `r”
    }
```

Updated Script:

```
    #################### # Get AD Site List # #################### 
Write-Verbose “Get AD Site List r” 
$ADSites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites 
#$adsites= @{} 
$ADSitesCount = $ADSites.Count 
Write-Output “There are $ADSitesCount AD Sites r” 
$properties = @{'SiteName'=$ADSites.Name; 'SiteServers'=$ADSites.server; } 
$object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties 
Write-Output $object
```

Comment: First: this is not how this community works. you try first and if you have problems with your code you come here and ask. Also you allready have a object that contains everything and its called `$ADSites`

Comment: You would need to show us the desired output or give the Comminuty something to go on. As @Paul mentions you already have this information in an object. If you are only looking for certain properties you could just use `Select-Object` to get the properties you want. Don't know what you want `$Site | Get-Member -MemberType Property` or just `Get-Member`

Comment: i know that part .i want hastable so that the output is in the correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
$properties = @{'SiteName'=$ADSites.Name; 'SiteServers'=$ADSites.server; }
```

$ADSites is an array. It contains all sitenames so what you will create looks like this:

```
Sites
----
{a, b, c}
```

The solution is to create an array that holds multiple objects and add one object per site:

```
$collection= @()
foreach($site in $ADSites){
 $properties = @{ "Name" =$site.Name; "SiteServers"=$site.Server}
 $collection +=(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties )
}
$collection
```

Write-Output is used to output to the pipeline not for producing screen output

Comment: Thanks for the help Paul actually i tried what you suggested before putting this in the forum i found out my mistake if you see the script for $adsites which i have commented out instead of using parenthesis i was using getting curly brackets actually the below script also works which is more the same instead of put collection array out i have put inside for each i am not able to put the script here but thks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just might be over thinking this but this will give you the same information that you are going for in a table format simply using `Select-Object` to get only the properties you want

```
$ADSites = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().Sites
Write-Output “There are $($ADSites.Count) AD Sites `r” 
$ADSites | Select-Object name,servers
```

**Obfuscated output**

```
There are 4 AD Sites 

Name                                               Servers                                          
----                                               -------                                          
SITE1                                              {SERVER1.DOMAIN.NET, SERVER2.DOMAIN.NET}           
STE345                                             {SERVER3.DOMAIN.NET}                               
LOCCOMP                                            {SERVER4.DOMAIN.NET}                                
THING                                              {SERVER9720.DOMAIN.NET, SERVER7.DOMAIN.NET}
```

Comment: i know matt but for some reason my server side comes empty don't know why

Comment: found out my mistake instead of using servers i was using server feel bad now what a waste of time :) Anyways learned new thing :)